# How to "Merge" a table of dates with exclusive employee names by day

Tags: powerquery, m

I have two tables, one with dates and another one with names and what I'd like to do is "merge" this two tables into another one like the example bellow assining for each day only one person repeating after the last one (F).

[tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRBWA.png)

Tks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this setup

[image: Table]

[image: Table2]

Read each step name:

```
let
    Origen = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Tabla1"]}[Content],
    ExtractDates = Table.AddColumn(Origen, "SingleDate", each Text.BeforeDelimiter([Date], " "), type text),
    ChangeTypes = Table.TransformColumnTypes(ExtractDates,{{"SingleDate", type date}}),
    AddDayOfWeek = Table.AddColumn(ChangeTypes, "Día de la semana", each Date.DayOfWeek([SingleDate]), Int64.Type),
    FilterWeekends = Table.SelectRows(AddDayOfWeek, each ([Día de la semana] <> 0 and [Día de la semana] <> 6)),
    AddIndex = Table.AddIndexColumn(FilterWeekends, "Índice", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    RestartIndexEverySixRows = Table.TransformColumns(AddIndex,{{"Índice", (index) => Number.Mod(index, 6) + 1, type number}}),
    MergeTablePerson = Table.NestedJoin(RestartIndexEverySixRows, {"Índice"}, TablePerson, {"ID"}, "TableLetter", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    ExpandName = Table.ExpandTableColumn(MergeTablePerson, "TableLetter", {"Name"}, {"Name"}),
    RemoveCols = Table.RemoveColumns(ExpandName,{"Día de la semana", "Índice"}),
    MergeExpandName = Table.NestedJoin(ExtractDates, {"Date"}, ExpandName, {"Date"}, "Se expandió TableLetter", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    ExpandName2 = Table.ExpandTableColumn(MergeExpandName, "Se expandió TableLetter", {"Name"}, {"Name"}),
    OrderByDate = Table.Sort(ExpandName2,{{"SingleDate", Order.Ascending}}),
    RemoveCol = Table.RemoveColumns(OrderByDate,{"SingleDate"})
in
    RemoveCol
```

Comment: Fantastic @Ricardo Diaz, It works like a charm. Just minor adjustments in my setup. Now I'll study your code to identify what i was doing wrong.